# Convert outlook PST to IMAP Maildir

Tags: imap, outlook, maildir

I'm currently migrating users from an Exchange to an IMAP Postfix server using Maildir format mailboxes.

For now i've been copying mails on outlook from the PST to the new IMAP mailbox, but it's taking REALLY long (almost 30min for 100 mails !).

Is there a tool to do it automatically and with more efficiency ? 
I've found lot of ppl trying to get PST to mbox but noone to get PST to maildir..

Cheers

Comment: you could got to mbox first then to maildir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright in fact it wasn't the conversion from pst to imap which was slowing the shit here.
While copying, the exchange account was still opened on outlook and, strange thing, its connections tries on its exchange server blocked the pst->imap connection.

Clicking on "Cancel all server requests" in the traybar bypass this, but simply removing the exchange account from outlook before the conversion is better.